# PHP Generated CSV attachment seems to lose part of first line via Outlook but not Gmail

Tags: php, csv, freebsd, outlook-2010

I have a PHP script running via cron under FreeBSD 8.0, sendmail, PHP 5.2.11 (cli).

The first row of the CSV is defined by this line:

```
$content .= "\n" .  'first_name,last_name,address1,address2,city,state_province,postal_code,country' . "\n";
```

Prior to a move to the current server this script worked fine however now it has an  glitch:

If the email is received via Outlook the first line looks like this in Excel:

```
ate_province    postal_code country
```

and this in a text editor:

```
ate_province,postal_code,country
```

I added an extra "\n" to the beginning and saw it added one character to the abridged string so I tried added 31 and sure enough Outlook, my text editor, and Excel see a perfect file.

Then I logged into Gmail and downloaded what should be the exact same file as it is the exact same email.  I open it in Excel and my text editor and what should I find but 31 newlines...

Anyone have any advice on what is happening?

// Per request link to email with headers
http://pastebin.com/wuyVf9HP

// EDIT adding whole mail routine per XzKto's request

```
if (fwrite($handle, $content) === FALSE) {
  die("Cannot write to file ($filename)");
}
$message = "Here is the file (comma-separated values) of addresses for\n";
$message .= $pm_row['title'] . " Requests ($now_YmdHMS).\n\n";
$data_email = $pm_row['fulfillment_data_email'];
$data_email_cc = "$pm_row[fulfillment_data_email_cc],$developer_email";
$subject = $pm_row['title'] . " Requests ($now_YmdHMS)";
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
$headers = "From: xxxx <tourism@xxx.org>\r\nReply-To: tourism@xxx.org\r\nCc:$data_email_cc"; 
$headers .= "\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));
$output = "
--PHP-mixed-$random_hash; 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary='PHP-alt-$random_hash'
--PHP-alt-$random_hash
Content-Type: text/plain; charset='iso-8859-1'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message

--PHP-alt-$random_hash 
Content-Type: text/html; charset='iso-8859-1'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message

--PHP-alt-$random_hash--

--PHP-mixed-$random_hash
Content-Type: application/zip; name=$now_YmdHMS.$pm_row[handle].csv
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";
mail($data_email, $subject, $output, $headers);
```

Comment: Very strange! I know windows requires carriage return and a line feed for a line end, whereas unix just requires the line feed - that might have something to do with it...

Comment: If you get some unexpected results when sending emails most likely you broke RFC when you generated message source. When email works OK in one place and is broken in another it doesn't mean that the second place has some bugs, most likely it is the first place that somehow fixed you email source to make it work(which really shouldn't happen). We need to understand how you generate email source to help you better.

Comment: @Steveo - I had considered this as well but we've been doing these with just \n for years without issue.  I tried changing to \r\n early in my debugging to no effect.

Comment: @XzKto - that's a good point.  I have added the whole mail routine's code as an edit above.

Comment: Can open the received mail in gmail in "show original" and put the result somewhere on the web (pastebin e.g.)?

Comment: @ott - here's the Email source with the middle of the attchment snipped: http://pastebin.com/wuyVf9HP

Comment: I noticed the content-type "Content-Type: application/zip;". I use text/csv for a similar task. Maybe outlook tries to unzip something?

Comment: Updated it and ran; headers now show Content-Type: text/csv; name=20110919154215.gtg2011-2.csv for the attachment but Outlook still cuts the characters and Gmail still shows them.

Comment: I posted my way: http://pastebin.com/depDEmKf - one difference is I specify the \r\n explicitly while your content will contain \n only. I wonder if that makes the difference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3599/discussion-between-ott-and-jerrygarciuh)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will resolve the problem or not, but my suggestion would be to try using [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/fputcsv) instead of building the CSV file by hand.

Usage would look something like the following:

```
$fp = fopen('output.csv', 'w');
$fields = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'address1', .....);
$rows = func_that_returns_data();

fputcsv($fp, $fields);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```